# Is it possible to fetch blog post on blog.wordpress using API, webservices?

Tags: wordpress

If i create a blog account on wordpress.com, is it possible that I can fetch those blog post, does wordpress.com has any API or web services I can use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS: [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) or [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) or *non WP-based:* [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/) or [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)